# Fuga de memoria en WPF Image en ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, manejo-de-memoria

Tengo el siguiente diseño en mi app WPF:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PrinterApp.Views.Printer.Step1View"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PrinterApp.Views.Printer"
 xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:PrinterApp.Converters"
 xmlns:vpanel="clr-namespace:WpfToolkit.Controls;assembly=VirtualizingWrapPanel"
 xmlns:printer="clr-namespace:PrinterApp.ViewModels.Printer"
 mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded"
 d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <printer:PrintProcessViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<UserControl.Resources>

    <converters:HasImagesConverter x:Key="HasImagesConverter"/>
    <converters:HasNotImagesConverter x:Key="HasNotImagesConverter"/>
    <converters:ImagesCountConverter x:Key="ImagesCountConverter"/>

</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="38"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <local:StepIndicator Grid.Row="0"/>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" ContentStringFormat="{}{0} imágenes encontradas" FontWeight="Black" Content="{Binding CantAllImages}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource SecondaryLabel}" Foreground="{DynamicResource PrimaryBrush}"  FontSize="22"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" ContentStringFormat="{}{0} imágenes cargadas" FontWeight="Black" Content="{Binding CantCopy}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource SecondaryLabel}" Foreground="{DynamicResource PrimaryBrush}"  FontSize="22"/>

        <ListBox x:Name="ImgListBox" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  SelectionMode="Multiple"  Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding AllImages}" Grid.Row="1" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding}" MaxWidth="120" MaxHeight="120" Margin="5"></Image>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>

    <Button Content="Continuar" Background="#01A870" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Grid.Row="2" Style="{DynamicResource PrimaryButton}" Click="Next" Visibility="{Binding Images, Converter={StaticResource HasImagesConverter}}"/>
    <Button Content="Cancelar" Background="#ED1B28"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Grid.Row="2" Style="{DynamicResource PrimaryButton}" Click="Cancelar_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

como pueden notar tengo la propiedad `AllImages` vinculada al ListBox, aqui les dejo su definición:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> allImages = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> AllImages
{
  get => allImages;
}
```

Lo que deseo es poder hacer que las imagenes se vayan agregando según las vaya obteniendo, ya que debos copiarlas y luego obtener la ruta y es un proceso largo me gustaria hacerlo en segundo plano para que el usuario pueda ir eligiendo imagenes en el ListBox sin necesidad de esperar a que todas estén cargadas, la carga esta solucionada pero cuando quiero agregar nuevas rutas de imágenes a la colección se genera una fuga de memoria al ejecutar esto:

```
public void AddToState(List<string> paths)
{
   Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
   {
      foreach (var path in paths)
      {
         _vm.AllImages.Add(path);
      }
   }));
}
```

Aqui una foto de la fuga de memoria:
[image: Herramienta de Diagnostico]

Comment: Hola, no estaras duplicando los items agregados? porque volves a hacer un foreach y no agregas uno a uno las siguientes imagenes? o algun metodo te trae el listado?

Comment: Tengo un metodo que me escanea todas las fotos y luego voy copiando de 50 en 50 al disco y retorno cada 50 rutas de las imagenes y la agrego con un foreach a mi ObservableCollection<string> que se enlaza al Listbox

Comment: El listbox, si no saque mal los calculos tiene 3 y 4 megas. Ese me parece que no seria el problema. Debe ser otro array donde si guardas las fotos porque en el listbox estas guardando texto.

Comment: Pero si dejo de asignar los elementos al ListBox se mantiene estable la memoria

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar una `Task` para que tu tarea se ejecute en segundo plano y usar el `yield` que sirve para ir devolviendo los elementos mientras recorres un listado.

```
ImgListBox.ItemsSource = GetImages();

public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetImages(List<string> paths)
{  
      foreach (var path in paths)
      {
        yield return path;
      }  
}
```

> https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield

Deberias iterar el listado donde recibes esas imagenes y no andar pasando el listado por otro lado, para volver a iterarlo.

Comment: Entonces no tendría que hacer un bind para ir agregando dinamicamente las imagenes, no lo había pensado. Ire a probar que tal.